# Hibernate Dao service instead of repository.JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I wanted to use a dao and service layer for my test project but for some reason i get a java.lang.NullPointerException: null.

This is the working example :

UserController :

```
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user) {

        return repo.saveAndFlush(user);
    }}
```

UserRepository :

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,String> {

    // Optional<User> findOneByLogin(String login);

}
```

But i replace it with this: I used following tutorial as guide [Hibernate JPA DAO Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-dao-example/)

UserDao

```
public class UserDao implements UserDaoInterface <User,Integer> {

    private Session currentSession;

    private Transaction currentTransaction;

    public org.hibernate.Session openCurrentSession() {
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        return currentSession;
    }

    public org.hibernate.Session openCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
        return currentSession;
    }

    public void closeCurrentSession() {
        currentSession.close();
    }

    public void closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
        currentTransaction.commit();
        currentSession.close();
    }

    private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return currentSession;
    }

    public void setCurrentSession(Session currentSession) {
        this.currentSession = currentSession;
    }

    public Transaction getCurrentTransaction() {
        return currentTransaction;
    }

    public void setCurrentTransaction(Transaction currentTransaction) {
        this.currentTransaction = currentTransaction;
    }

    public UserDao() {

    }

    @Override
    public void create(User user) {
        getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }
```

Could it be that the sessions returns null? Why and how to fix this ?

UserService

```
public class UserService {

    private static UserDao userDao;

    public UserService (){

        userDao = new UserDao();

    }

    public void save (User user){

        userDao.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
        userDao.create(user);
        userDao.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();


    }

}
```

And finally 
UserController

public class UserController {

```
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addUser(@RequestBody User user) {

        userService.save(user);

    }}
```

I don't know if this has anything to do with this but i also get this in the error log

```
at demo.security.SecurityConfiguration$1.doFilterInternal(SecurityConfiguration.java:119)
```

public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
//For more information check spring documentation
private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
    return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                    .getName());
            if (csrf != null) {
                Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                String token = csrf.getToken();
                if (cookie == null || token != null
                        && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                    cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response); // this is line 119
        }
    };
}}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login5
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#Hibernate Configuration:
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
entitymanager.packages.to.scan=com.spr.model
```

** Edit **

So i did what Анатолій Вакалюк suggested 
Added @Repository And @ Service annotation so spring can manage this.

But now i get following error :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

I'm using spring boot do i need to use xml configuration for this.

Comment: You did'n mark userService field in UserController with `@Autowired` annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a NullPointeException because your UserDao is not managed by Spring context. You have to annotate your DAO with @Repository, and after that you can inject/autowire it in service like this:

```
@Autowire
private UserDao userDao;
```

The same thing is with your service. You have to annotate it with @Service and autowire it in your controller.

Also if you are configured JPA, you need to use [EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) instead of Hibernate Session

**Edit**

If you want to customize Spring Data repository you can declare your own interface with custom methods:

```
public interface CustomRepository {
  //custom methods here
}
```

And provide implementation for it:

```
public class CustomRepositoryImpl implements CustomRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    //custom methods implementation
}
```

And after that just extend your repository with custom interface:

```
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer>, CustomRepository {
   //you have both spring data and custom methods here
```

}

See this article for more details. [Customize spring data repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations)

Comment: So now i used @Entity on user, Repository on UserDao And Service on UserService. But  Now i get following error :org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found. I am using spring boot do i need an xml file ?

Comment: You need to add @EntityScan annotation to your config and specify package in which your entities in.   http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityScan.html

Comment: Thanks, You really helped me understand spring a bit better.